# javascript split not running on IE

Tags: javascript

I have been using the split function just to split the date but the code doesnt work on IE although works fine with other browser.ul,li is dynamically generated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
            <tr>

               <td id="getexp">
                <ul class="zoneSubscriptions">
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="zoneName"><a href="/xyz.com">thats my info</a></li>
                            <li>5/04/2012</li>
                            <li>792.00 Yearly</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cancel</a></li>
                         </ul>
                     </li>
                 </ul>
               </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
function getText()
{   
    var val = document.getElementById('getexp').innerHTML;
    var val1=(val.split("<ul>"));
    var val1=(val.split("<li>"));
    var dat=val1[2];
    var res=(dat.split("</li>"));
    alert(res[0]);
}
getText();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ul, li tag in IE will be <UL></UL>, <LI></LI>. (Upper-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `split` here. You can get all `li` in one [`Nodelist`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/obj_nodelist.html) object like this:

```
var res = document.getElementById('getexp').getElementsByTagName('li');
alert(res[0]);
```

**EDIT** based on comment: if you really need `split`, you can use a regular expression to ensure case insensitivity. Furthermore, if it's the innerHTML of the second <ul>, give that <ul> an **id** (say 'data'). If it's the date you're after, you are looking for the second element of the array the `split` delivers you (arrays are [*zero based*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array)) Your function can be simplified to:

```
function getText()
{   
    var val = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML.split(/<li>/i);
      , res = val[1].replace(/<\/li>/i,'');
    alert( res );

    //now if you want to increase the year in the date:
    var dat = res.split(/\//);
    dat[2] = parseInt(dat[2],10)+1;
    val[1] = dat.join('/')+'</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i do have to split the values of the date as i need update those individually for that i have to use the split function which creates the problem                                                                                                                                     var res = document.getElementById('getexp').getElementsByTagName('li');
alert(res[2].innerHTML);                                              i have to add 1 year in the date which is displaying and pass it